# How do I do Android development from multiple computers?

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

Well I'm giving Android development a shot, and I want to work on the same Android code from multiple PCs (e.g. office and home PC) .. The problem is, I'm using SVN to sync the Android workspace folders, but when I do the SVN update on a PC, and then open/import the project in Eclipse, I get all kinds of errors ..

Previously I did the above for syncing the 'Projects' folder for Visual Studio 2010 via SVN, and it worked brilliantly ..

How can share the same Android workspace across multiple PCs as well, without having to manually copy over code to the other machine, and having to manually import it everytime I switch PCs .. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since everybody presented how you can do it with SVN. I would like to suggest you something else. I once tried to do it with a cloud service e.g. Google Cloud, Drobbox etc. You could just create a Project in a Dropbox folder and everytime you switch computers just clean your project.

Regards, also Ahmad :)

Comment: Thanks Ahmad for your suggestion :) .. I just tried using it with Dropbox, and its working brilliantly ! I save stuff in one location, and then open it on another PC, and its loading everything automatically. Sometimes I don't even need to run Clean! Just one point though for others reading. For this to work, you need to *close* your IDE on one PC, have Dropbox sync everything, and then open your IDE on another PC and load the workspace from Dropbox .. Simply 'closing' a project at one location and opening it at another location and then refreshing won't work. IDE's need to be closed !

Answer (score 2):

I already developed using SVN or git.

You need to create a project in each computer, but don't use import. Save only the java files + proguard file + manifest file + .classpath and the .project in the SVN/git. Then, in each computer (you only need to do this once) create a new project and use the option on eclipse "create project from existent source".

Sometimes you need to rebuild your project using Build > Clean.

Answer (score 1):

please supply information about what kind of errors you get.

I suspect that you're trying to commit an non-updated project.
so before working on your project it's highly recommended to do "update"

I think the errors occur because you're trying to commit an non-updated file
which will probably cause a collision.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [SVN Plugin](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseSubversive/article.html) here is tutorial of [how to install SVN in eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseSubversive/article.html)

Then upload only Java files/src, resource folder and Manifest file on SVN server.

from other PC you can create/import project directly from SVN plugin. And some files like gen/bin will be automatically generate. 
Now u need to clean the project and u are ready to use.

Now before committing files/changes on SVN, You need to update your code first from SVN plugin, so it dont result in conflicts..

Answer (score 0):

as per i understand you code in ur office as well as home. So now u need the same code changes what ever u did in office to reflect in your home PC as well.
for this first thing is is ur home PC also connected to the SVN.
IF YES - 
while working in office always "COMMIT" your changes.Then after going home always take UPDATE of the same project and then start coding, if you are dome with your changes in HOME then before leaving HOME PC COMMIT your changes.
Then again before start working on your OFFICE PC take an update then start coding.
If you are doing this then it should work fine.
If still you are getting errors then in Eclipse click on WINDOW the click on SHOW VIEW then select PROBLEMS... i.e WINDOW>SHOW VIEW>PROBLEMS there you would see some issues as error, paste them here so that we get clear idea. May be some classpath issues.
you can open your project folder, there look for classpath file, see if classpath is right for the JARS that you might be using.

Answer (score 0):

**If you already use a standalone SVN client like Cornerstone or Versions**, make sure you svn ignore the following directories, as they are specific to your workspace and will cause problems when you try to checkout and import to a project on another machine:

- .settings
- bin
- gen

After you've checked in your source files without these, you can create a new project from your working copy on a second machine using File > Import > Existing Android Code Into Workspace.